# Am I right using ajax and pass the parameter. It seems the web method is not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax, post, webmethod

I'm trying to pass the id parameter to the web method using `Ajax`.

I added

```
<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" %>, using System.Web.Services, opened a comment [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.changeImage').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr("ID");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                //url: "WebService.asmx/MyMethod",
                url: '<%= ResolveUrl("WebService.asmx/MyMethod") %>',
                data: '{id: "' + id + '"}',
                dataType: "json",
                async: "false",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string MyMethod(int id)
    {
        return "Hello World" + id.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Is the method really in an asmx web service, or in the page's code behind?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: in WebService.cs

Comment: In the first line of the code (toolkit) there's some extra stuff at the end. Can you fix that plz. Make sure it's not in the original.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn’t understand your question very well. For some reason,when I change public string MyMethod(int id) to string id I get alert("Success"). 
But still getting the message "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below." <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello world 5 </string>.

Comment: Look at the first line of code starting with `<%@ Register Namespace=...`. There's some stuff at the end that looks it like shouldn't be there: `, using System.Web.Services, opened a comment [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]`.

Comment: Are you mean to open comment ? It opened. [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)] 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: **Look at your first line of code** -- scroll to the right.

Comment: Are you about "<%@ Register Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" tagPrefix="ajax" %>, using System.Web.Services, opened a comment [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]"?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `static` classifier in MyMethod.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string MyMethod(int id)
        {
            return "Hello World" + id.ToString();
        }
```

Try running accessing and using web-service in browser first. If it works then try to access it in your code.

[image]

Also Can you post the error that you are getting? use `debugger;` statement in the javascript to get the exact error.

Comment: I see web service in browser, but the method fails, probably because the parameter is passed on click? I don't get any error. Only alert("Error").

Comment: Сan there be a mistake in what I write "string userId = Context.User.Identity.GetUserId();" ?

Comment: When I changed method to [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
        public string MyMethod(int id)
        {
            return "Hello World" + id.ToString();
        }   I got This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.    <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">Hello World1</string>

Comment: use chrome dev tools (F12 on chrome window) to see exact error. Before that add ```debugger;``` statement inside the method.

Comment: Thank you very much for dev tools! The following error appears "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". 
I read that  the 500 code indicate an error on the server. And I tried to find a solution, but it’s not working yet.

Comment: I also added <script type="text/javascript"> debugger;
    $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: put  the ```debugger;``` inside ready function. and keep developer toolbar open while debugging. debugging opens in chrome not in visual studio.

Comment: Ok, I put debugger inside ready function and debugging opens in chrome. I have such an error "jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 POST http://localhost/MyProject/WebService.asmx/MyMethod 500 (Internal Server Error)" When I expand menu of error :  send @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9837
ajax @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9434
(anonymous) @ Index.aspx:216
dispatch @ jquery-3.4.1.js:5237
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.4.1.js:5044

Comment: When I go over "send @ jquery-3.4.1.js:9837" link, I get  "// Do send the request (this may raise an exception) xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );"

Comment: {r.send(i.hasContent&&i.data||null)}catch(e){if(o)throw e}},abort:function().......

Comment: The problem is almost solved. The web service is working. I just pass the wrong id. When alert(id) I get "ContentplaceHolder_1". How to get pure id without ContentPlaceHolder?

Comment: Somebody please mark  it solved, because I do not have enough privileges to do this.